# Can't sort a list by datasets when actively trying to change dataset values

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery, cefsharp

I'm writing an application in C# with Cefsharp. I'm utilizing C#, JavaScript and HTML/CSS for this project.

I recently posted a question about issues with sorting a list based on the innerHTML text of the said item (the text included the index of the list item) in the list. I received help with this, however the demands changed a bit and I can no longer have the index number in the actual text.

I managed to solve this by using datasets in HTML instead. I was having issues making the list sort but I was sure that it technically should work so I isolated everything in jsfiddle. Everything worked perfectly, so I decided to add a few of the elements in my function at a time.

I found out that the sorting stops working because I'm trying to change the values of my datasets. The actual value of the datasets are succesfully changing, however the sorting stops working for some reason. If I'm NOT trying to change the values of the datasets, it works perfectly. These are the relevant codes:

WinForms function (redacted, executed every 1000ms):

```
private async void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach (var order in orderResult.OrderResult.Select((value, i) => (value, i)))
   {
        chromeBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync("updateOrderQueue", order.i, order.value.Reference, order.value.PickedUpAt == "" ? "" : order.value.PickedUpAt,
                            order.value.DeliveredTo == "" ? "" : order.value.DeliveredTo, order.value.RobotId.Length > 0 ? order.value.RobotId.Remove(0, 4) : order.value.RobotId,
                            order.value.StatusCode, status.GetOrderStatus(order.value.StatusCode));
   }
}
```

JavaScript functions:

```
function updateOrderQueue(index, reference, pickedup, deliveredto, robotId, statuscode, statustext) {
    var list = $('ul#orderQueueList');
    var count = $("ul#orderQueueList li").length;
    var item = jQuery("#order" + jq(reference));
    var robotQueue = jQuery("#robotQueue" + jq(reference))

    if (!document.getElementById('order' + reference) && statuscode < 4 && count < 9) {
        var data = $(`<li data-indexn="` + index + `" class="list-group-item list-group-item-secondary d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center border border-dark" id="order` + reference + `">
                        <h3 class="mt-1" id="text`+ reference + `">
                            `+ index + `) ` + pickedup + ` ➔ ` + deliveredto + ` (` + statustext + `)
                        </h3>
                        <small class="badge badge-dark rounded" style="font-size:24px;" id="robotQueue`+ reference + `">` + robotId + `</small>
                    </li>`);
        data.appendTo(list).hide().fadeIn(500);
    } else {
        var locations = jQuery("#text" + jq(reference));
        var assignedrobot = jQuery("#robotQueue" + jq(reference));
        locations.text(index + ') ' + pickedup + ' ➔ ' + deliveredto + ' (' + statustext + ')');
        assignedrobot.text(robotId);
    }

    item.attr("data-indexn", index);
    
    sortList();
}

function sortList() {
    $("#orderQueueList li").sort(function (a, b) {
        return parseInt($(a).data('indexn')) - parseInt($(b).data('indexn'));
    }).appendTo('#orderQueueList');
}
```

When this code is removed from my JavaScript function, everything works as intended:

```
item.attr("data-indexn", index);
```

This is the list in the HTML code:

```
<ul id="robotQueue">
    <li id="order######" data-indexn="0">
       TEXT
    </li>
</ul>
```

I've tried to isolate as much as I can to try and find what causes it but I can't figure it out. Sorry if the post is a bit long.

Thanks!

Comment: Are there any errors or warnings in the DevTools console? https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#javascript-debugging is there a reason you sort every loop iteration? Sorting after you've finished updating would be more efficient.

Comment: @amaitland I'm gonna have a look at that first things first tomorrow when I get access to my programming laptop again. I don't have a specific reason for doing so no, how would you propose it should be done instead? I thought I already was sorting after updating as the function first updates everything and then sorts it at the end of the function, correct me if I'm wrong. And what makes it more efficient? Thank you for your pointers, sir.

Comment: I have no way to run your code, so I can only say how it reads. You have a foreach loop which calls updateOrderQueue, potentially multiple times, once per loop iteration, sorting on each update. Better to call sort outside the loop.

Comment: @amaitland Yeah that makes sense and idk why that flew over my head. I checked the DevTools window and there does not seem to be any errors. I did some additional troubleshooting. I added a way for me to manually add items in the list, these sort perfectly fine both manually and automatically. When the system adds items in the list based on what it finds in the data from the API, it does NOT work. I'm not sure if this is because of how I'm updating the "data-indexn" or for some other reason. I'm kind of stuck right now.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I'm not sure if this *actually* counts as an answer or not. According to everything I've been reading, the use of the **attr()** method should work perfectly fine to set values for datasets (which is what I *tried* to do). It does succesfully set new values for each item but it also messes with the sorting for some reason, making it not work anymore.

Couldn't find any reason as to why this would not work however I tried setting the values with the **data()** method instead, example below:

```
function updateDataset() {
   var item = $("#order");
   item.data("indexn", value); // "data-indexn" in HTML would be only "indexn" here
}
```

This worked perfectly fine and the code now runs without **any issues**.

Again, I'm not sure why **attr()** did not work and there might be a better answer for this question but I'm posting this here in case someone else has a similar problem.